# Update datatable info after filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

[LIVE DATATABLES](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/56/edit)

The Datatable has two filters for searches:

1. A regular `text input`
2. A `Status` select

With the first filter, the table works as expected.

The second filter is a select that filters the status (Active or Inactive) without being text-based like the first filter.

The problem is the following:

Let's say I type `d` in the search input and no status is selected:

[image]

I'm getting 4 entries.

This is the text I get:

`Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries (filtered from 7 total entries)`

If I select now a status, for example `Active`, I get 3 results.

[image]

This is the text I get:

`Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries (filtered from 7 total entries)`

But it should be: `Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries (filtered from 7 total entries)`

I think the problem is that I would have to redraw the table after applying the non-text based filter. But I do not know how to do that.

What I've tried (not working, since I am hiding the rows using CSS):

```
$('#search2').on('change', () => {
  const state = $("#search2").val();
  if (state === "none") {
    $(".status-active").parent().parent().attr("hidden", false);
    $(".status-inactive").parent().parent().attr("hidden", false);
    return;
  }

  $(".status-" + ((state === "active") ? 'inactive' : 'active')).parent().parent().attr("hidden", true);
  $(".status-" + state).parent().parent().attr("hidden", false);
  DT1.search(state).draw();
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I found

```
$('#search2').on('change', () => {
    const state = $("#search2").val();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    if (state === "none") {
      DT1.draw();
      return;
    }
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, searchData, index, rowData) {
      const $td = DT1.row(index).nodes().to$().find('td');
      return $td.find(`.status-${state}`).length;
    });
    DT1.draw();
  });
```

So to make sure the data is not hidden or removed but only filtered, we should use built-in search method.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

This one is to make sure the data is in unfiltered condition when you are about to filter data.

```
if (state === "none") {
  DT1.draw();
  return;
}
```

When you are not filtering, we just have to draw the table and return. Because the previous line we make sure the tables is not filtered at all

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()
```

Here is what I found in the internet, the solution. I cannot explain this one actually.

```
const $td = DT1.row(index).nodes().to$().find('td');
```

This one is to get all the `<td>` in the table, maybe you can improve this one to find only desired td but this one already works though.

```
return $td.find(`.status-${state}`).length;
```

After we find the td tag, we have to make sure that we found the class that we desire. If not found then return 0

```
DT1.draw();
```

And then draw the filtered table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! (it is not clear to me how it works 100% tho)

Comment: `Update: It does not work :(`
It works (partially) but it is not consistent. 
It does the job eventually but if you keep selecting states, at some point it stops working. Could you test it a little to see if you find the bug and thus be able to accept your answer as valid (I upvoted)? Please feel free to edit the live datatable that I created.

Comment: Could you explain how to reproduce the bug? I cannot reproduce it

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I copied and pasted your answer into my code, it is not working...please take a look: http://live.datatables.net/doxojaco/2/edit
The active/inactive it is not even working :/

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if that will help you reproduce the bug but sometimes it happens to me: 1. Input text search (that will load some results, let's say 3 rows with status = active) 2. Select status (`Inactive`) -that will return 0 results- 
3. Select the default select value again '`Select a Status`'
4. No results are displayed (it should be 3 rows with status = `Active`

Comment: http://live.datatables.net/racanida/1/edit actually i find that  DT1.row(index).nodes().to$().find('td:eq(2)') is used to find 'only' the second column, so if you change your 'status column' to the first column you have to edit it to td:eq(1). You actually can use DT1.row(index).nodes().to$().find('td') witout eq to find all column inside of your row. 

And for the the bug, you have to console.log(state) to see if the state is changed. Because it never happen to me either in jsbin or in my local browser. My assumption is that the on('change') is not even called

Comment: It works now, thanks for your help. Hope this can help someone in the future.